# Spawning unique groups Game Maker

Tags: game-maker, gml

Completely new to all this so bear with me. I don't know what I don't know.

Every second or two I'm wanting a column of 5 random objects from a pool of 20 to spawn in from the right. What I can't figure out where to start on is if I want there to be no repeats of the same object for at least 2 columns over.

The columns start spawning from the right and make their way left, the first column is obviously a free one, but how do I not allow any of the objects from the first to be in the 2nd and 3rd. and any from the 2nd to be in the 3rd and the 4th and so on?

columns 1- 3 could have numbers 1-15 and then column 4 could start having 1-5 again in addition to the other unused from the 20.

Not sure if this is monstrous or not.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a 'ds_stack' of enemies and spawn them from that.

```
enemyStack = ds_stack_create();
ENEMY_AMOUNT = /*AMOUNT OF ENEMIES*/
```

Create an array of enemies and then use a 'for' loop to add them to it.

```
for (var i=0;i<ENEMY_AMOUNT;i++)
{
    ds_stack_push(enemyStack,enemy[i]);
}
```

Then when you want to spawn them

```
for (var i=0;i<SPAWN_AMOUNT;i++)
{
    instance_create(xx,yy,ds_stack_pop(enemyStack);
}
```

remember to destroy the stack

```
ds_stack_destroy(enemyStack);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't know how to compare if two objects are equal. For every object game maker creates a unique index that you can get through the *object_index()* function. Also you probably doesn't know how to handle [data structures][1]. (arrays are not the optimal in this case)

First you initialize an data structure with all the classes from where you can choose at random wich enemy to create. Then you choose one a random and remove that obj from the data structure, so it won't be selected in the next random draw.